# Swift tableviewcell bounds not binding/pinned properly?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, autolayout

So as I am trying to customize the table view cells for a little "get to learn iOS swift" project I ran into a snag. When attempting to pin my image view objects they disappear. Im not sure what Im doing wrong here but Ill try to give as much information as I can on my current setup.

I have a cell that will be populated dynamically. The picture below represents what I want to achieve ultimately.

The first things that come to my mind are the following.

1. Bind Image view 1 to the top and left corner of the cell, Fix their
   widths to 96 x 96
2. Bind Image view 2 to the bottom and left corner of the cell, Fix
   their widths to 96 x 96
3. Bind Full Name label to the left of the cell with a 8pt padding from
   image view 1 and the top of the cell with 0. Repeat for Job
   Description label and textview label
4. Bind DIST label to right and bottom of the cell

[image: List item]

What actually happens when I attempt the first step..
The image view just disapears. Im fairly new to swift and xcode so Im not sure if theres a different way to bind things when it comes down to table cells or am i just doing it wrong in general

[image]

Comment: Helping debug autolayout issues especially when using interface builder is a bit tough. Would it be possible for you to break this out into a sample project that illustrates the issue and post it? I should be able to help you figure it out then.

Comment: Does it work if I push it up onto github?

Comment: Absolutely, just post it and paste the link here.

Comment: Here it is! Thanks! https://github.com/sgedwardlim/swifttest

Comment: Running your project just gives me a blank (empty) tableview, can you modify it so there is actual content laid out? Also, I don't actually see any constraints in the storyboard. I am using Xcode 8 so perhaps there is an incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/subhajitregor/swifttest.git

Created the constraints for you, check out and just put your codes to work.
Your can run first to check it. Run and it will show 3 cells with the design working.

Note: I have converted it to swift 3 as i am working with xcode 8